# How to convert a flat json message in a kafka topic to something that can be imported to Opentsdb with tags

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, opentsdb

I just started working with OpenTSDB 2.4. I have these flat messages in a a kafka topic:

```
{
  "field_a": "transmit",
  "field_b": "10.20.30.254",
  "timestamp": 1624409678000,
  "bytes": 245
}
```

the way I would like to write this data to OpenTSDB is as follows:

```
[
{
    "metric": "netflow.bytes",
    "timestamp": 1624409678000,
    "value": 245,
    "tags": {
    "field_a": "transmit",
    "field_b": "10.20.30.254"
    }
}
]
```

Question is, how can I transform my data to look like the second one. Is it possible to do this without writing a custom Kafka-Connect plugin?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own custom Kafka consumer which does the transformation. It does not need to be a Kafka connect code.